# Two texts in the same line one aligned left the other centered

Tags: html, css, css-float, text-alignment

I have a silly problem.
I want two texts to stay in the same line, but one `text-align: left;` and the other one `text-align: center;`

What's the correct way to do that?

```css
.number{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  text-align:left;
  display:inline;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top:-10px; 
  float:left;
  font-size:18px;
}

.menutitle{
  display:block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
  margin-bottom:31px;
}
```

```html
<span class="number">00</span><span class="menutitle">TEXT</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
.element {
  display: flex;
}

.menutitle {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <span class="number">00</span>
  <span class="menutitle">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, I wasn't aware of that property. Still in my website there's a gap between the number and the text :/

Comment: It must be some of your other css that creates that gap. Maybe `width: 50px;` on `.number` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/109/